# Rails doesn't deserialize array back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I have a problem with serialization. 
In my model I have

```
class PramEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :pram_units_array, Array
  attr_accessible :pram_units_array
end
```

then I do

```
entry = PramEntry.new
entry.pram_units_array = [PramUnit.new(depth: 1, width: 1)]

entry.pram_units_array 
=> [#<PramUnit:0x007fb368eb8ae8 @depth=1, @width=1>]
entry.save
=> true
```

but then I load this object from database

```
entry = PramEntry.first
entry.pram_units_array
=>  "---\n- &70364639756800 !ruby/object:PramUnit\n  depth: 1\n  width: 1\n  errors: !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Errors\n    base: *70364639756800\n    messages: !omap []\n  validation_context: \n"
```

it doesn't serializes it back from yaml. What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found Answer to my question.

I've tried to deserialize manualy

```
YAML::load(PramEntry.last.pram_units_array)
=> ArgumentError: undefined class/module PramUnit
```

PramUnit is a ruby class in lib folder. I required it

```
require 'pram_unit'
```

even when I autoload files from lib.

```
 config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

It was very strange behavior for me. But problem was resolved :)